# How to make texture visible in unity from blender file?

Tags: unity, textures, blender, export

I've imported a tree to Unity that I've made in blender, but the texture of the tree is not visible. Could you please tell me how to make that texture visible? 
[image]

I am a beginer and I don't know how to actualy export it or what to select when exporting in blender. I only saved this 'maple' .blend file to my assets folder and that's it. I thought the tree would show up with the texture, but it didn't and I don't know what to do.

Comment: Did you try placing your texture in the Albedo slot of the tree's material? (Visible in the lower right of your screenshot)

Comment: Yes, I have added it to albedo, but it looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwycD.png

Comment: Looks like you neglected to enable alpha transparency on your leaf material. What happens when you do that?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know I can do such thing, it worked ^^

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please consider writing up the steps you used as an Answer. This can be a big help to fellow game developers who run into the same trouble you did.